# For each post variable insert into mysql database

Tags: php, html, mysql, css, database

I have a bit of code I use to print each variable I pass through a form to a processing script.

I have a database with the identical naming conventions and I want to post each variable. I know this has some security implications but it is the most practical solution given the amount of variables I have to pass.

This is my current script..

```
            <?php
            printArray($_POST);
            function printArray($array){
                 foreach ($array as $key => $value){
                    echo "$key => $value" . "<br>";
                    if(is_array($value)){ //If $value is an array, print it as well!
                        printArray($value);
                    }  
                } 
            }
            ?>
```

I know I can do something like this..

```
            <?php
            printArray($_POST);
            $sql = "INSERT INTO (applications) VALUES (";
            function printArray($array){
                 foreach ($array as $key => $value){
                    $sql .= "'" . $key."'";
                    echo $sql;
                    if(is_array($value)){ //If $value is an array, print it as well!
                        printArray($value);
                    }  
                } 
            }
            ?>
```

Is there an easier way to do this?

Comment: $_POST is insecure, use $post = filter_input_array(INPUT_POST, Appropriate filters here see php manual);

Answer (score 0):

something like this might work for you.

```
while( ($sql = your_filter_function(array_shift($_POST)) ) != NULL)
{
//do sql stuff here
}
```

Sorry for the lack of depth I am on mobile